# Get RAM usage of Android App programatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to build a feature for an android app which requires me to display RAM usage of an app. How do I get the RAM usage of an specific app(Eg: How to get the RAM usage of Google Chrome or Youtube?) I've looked at many threads on stack overflow and none of them seems to answer this question specifically. [How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-do-i-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android) - this comes close to answering it but doesn't answer it completely.

Comment: Not sure if you've read: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-management